# Screen pixels getting messed after Dialog is show full screen?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an activity and on click of button i show dialog which is custom. However when dialog is opened pixels of screen get messed up. I want to show dialog full screen following is my code.

```
final Dialog contactDialog = new Dialog(SettingsInformationActivity.this,R.style.DialogTheme);
contactDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
contactDialog.setContentView(R.layout.contact_dialog);
contactDialog.show();
```

Custom Dialog XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_id"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailsubject"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_subject"
        android:inputType="textEmailSubject" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <com.buzzreel.custom.HelveticaTextView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <com.buzzreel.custom.HelveticaTextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Style applied for fullscreen:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

    <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Whenever dialog opens this is messed up as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is probably due to this line `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`. Try removing this and it should work.